# Protect image from copy with itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext, copy-protection

We have to disable "Copy Image"-Function from a part of pdf file. Even not the hole File-protection. Just preventing direct copy. Is it possible?

We use iText to generate pdf.

Comment: I dont think that can be done , but you can give security to the pdf by passwords , check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425723/prevent-copying-pdf-contents-generated-using-itext

Comment: That is correct Bharath, but not all PDF viewers respect those settings; note that you can leave the user password blank (`null`) if you don't want the end user having to enter a password every time he opens the document.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestions. We resolve this issue with a simple transparent png layer. We place it absolut over the significant part of a document.